Continuously getting error while try to get the user from facebook
And also when i try to dump the error. It shows nothing at the place of $e->getMessage() . The output is

"Something went wrong!! : " // app\Http\Controllers\AuthController.php:77

config/services.php
 'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT'),
],

web.php
 Route::get('/auth/facebook', [AuthController::class, 'facebookPage'])->name('facebook.page');
Route::get('/auth/facebook/callback', [AuthController::class, 'facebookRedirect'])->name('facebook.redirect');

AuthController.php
 public function facebookPage(){
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function facebookRedirect(){
   try{
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        dd($user);
   }catch(Exception $e){
        dd('Something went wrong!! : ' . $e->getMessage() );
        
   } 
}

View file :
<a href="{{ url('/auth/facebook') }}">Login with Facebook</a>

